# Javascript Fullcalendar v4: Handler not working until I click on a button

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using the fullcalendar 4.0 Alpha version. I'm trying to register a dateClick listener. When I click on a date, nothing happens. After I click on the previous or next button and then on a date the listener is working. And the same problem when I use the "selectable" option. At first it is not working, but after I use the buttons it is working. This is how I initialize the calendar:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('my-fullcalendar');

    if (calendarEl) {
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

            // Options
            locale: 'de',
            firstDay: 1,
            selectable: true,

            // Handler
            dateClick: function() {
                alert('a day has been clicked!');
            }

        });

        calendar.render();
    }
});
```

It's a bit different than in the docs, but I had the same problem when I used the code from the docs. Does anyone have an idea why it is not working directly?

Comment: any console errors? As it's an alpha version, if you can consistently reproduce the problem in an isolated environment (e.g. in a JSFiddle, for example) it might be worth raising it as a bug.

Comment: Y downloaded the demo files of FullCalendar V4 alpha, and the selectable.html has the same problem :( I think, it happends when after the mousedown, when the "document" listen a mouseup